# KKT Condition and Global Optimal

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I just have some question about nonlinear constrained optimization.  If the problem satisfied the KKT condition and also the LICQ (linear independent constraint qualification), **do I simply compares all candidates points** $x_{candidate 1}, x_{candidate 2}, x_{candidate 3}..... x_{candidate _m}$ to get the **global optimum**, provided that the global optimal exists?

**Why do I need to do second order TEST??**

[image]

Comment: yes. But the number of candidates might be infinite.

Second order test will tighten the number of candidates

Comment: If the optimal exists, So just solving the sets of equations in the picture, and I get candidates. I simply compare each candidates to get the global optimal?